# Ideas for cmd to delete content of documents folder WIN 10?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, command

I want to create a .bat file with a command line inside that deletes all content of the C:\Users\Documents folder. I only want to delete the entire content of the folder, not the folder itself.

Why do I need this? Our company helps unemployed people find jobs and they use our laptops to create CVs and application lettres. They forget to delete their data (most of them don't really know how to use a computer) so I am trying to automate this process with a .bat file and a scheduled task (run script when user logs in).

If the laptops were WIN10 Pro, I would have used group policies in AD, but these computers are WIN10 home.

Any Ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: only files in the directory? what about sub directories?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why you'd want it to be scheduled to run at login. Can you explain how the user account(s) work? Does each unemployed person log in to the same account? or do they each have different ones? It makes more sense to create a user account for each attendee, then delete the account when that person no longer requires your services.

Comment: @Gerhard - Yes, I would also like to delete the subfolders

Comment: @Compo - The laptops have one account (standard, not admin) for all participants, in which they log in to. Your input is correct, I thought of that too, but we can't create user accounts for every participant, since we get up to 70 new persons per week AND since they work in different rooms, they will have to be able to use the computers provided in there (we don't give out laptops to users because in the past they were stolen and now thanks to covid the computers have to stay put where they are).

Comment: `del "C:\Users\Documents\*.*`.

Comment: @Mark - Thank you, but this only deletes the contents in the folder, but not the subfolders. Plus it asks for permission to delete, can I override this?

Comment: The issue with emptying a directory, especially a default Windows special folder like `Documents`, is that emptying the contents does not remove the system/registry locations which will still hold data related to those files etc. BTW to empty a directory, make it the current directory, then remove the directory and all of its subdirectories, _(because the directory is current it will remain untouched, but all of its content will be removed)_. For example: `@CD /D "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" 2> NUL && RD /S /Q .`, or `@PushD "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" 2> NUL && RD /S /Q . & PopD`

Comment: Type `del /?` for help on customising the command.

Comment: @ Compo - Thanks for your tip. I tried both scripts and changed %USERPROFILE%\Documents to "%BINplus TN%"\Documents (thats the name of the user account), but it did nothing. I tried with "%BINplus TN\Documents%" (I just tried with the % at the end) and it deleted everything on the desktop, but nothing in the documents folder... any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Jobcom, if the user account name is `BINplus TN`, and you don't want to use `%USERPROFILE%`, _(which I'd assume, at login, resolves to `C:\Users\BINplus TN`)_, then change it to either `@CD /D "C:\Users\BINplus TN\Documents" 2> NUL && RD /S /Q .`, or `@PushD "C:\Users\BINplus TN\Documents" 2> NUL && RD /S /Q . & PopD`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the `%userprofile%` part there. `%userprofile%` is an environment variable, use is as @Compo showed, do not change `%userprofile%` to `%anything else%` just `"%userprofile%\Documents"` will revert to `"C:\users\BINpus TN\Documents"` if that is your default user.

Comment: @Compo and Gerhard - Thank you, that woked perfectly! Great stuff!

Comment: @Jobcom another thing that you may want to note, GPEDIT is not actually a WIN PRO exclusive feature, it is just not activated by default on WIN HOME. Try using `dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~3*.mum` and `dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~3*.mum` and put the output files`dism /online /norestart /add-package:"Name"` where `Name` is each of the outputs of the dir. You have to do this in administrator mode though

Comment: @ Neko Musume - That is very interesting. We have certain computers running with AD and those have a log off script enabled. Does this now mean, I can use that same script for the win 10 home computers? Would I have to change the scriptparametres?

Answer (score 0):

One other way to do it is to copy an empty directory using `robocopy` to the documents folder. So as an example, Create a directory called `none`.
In this example, I created the empty directory as `D:\none`

```
robocopy "D:\none" "%userprofile%\Documents" /MIR
```

This will work from `cmd` and in a `batch-file`.

Comment: You won't believe me @Gerhard, but I actually have a USB thumb drive, which is often mounted as `D:`, and has a directory named `none`!

Comment: @Compo, well I suppose that is very coincidental, unless the `dir` is empty, then I doubt it to be a coincident, because I have exactly that!